# Show all tabs content vanilla js

Tags: javascript, tabs

How can I change this javascript code, that when I click on "Green" I want the content from all tabs to be displayed? https://codepen.io/wangel13/pen/OXBrRp

```js
'use strict';

function Tabs() {
  var bindAll = function() {
    var menuElements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-tab]');
    for(var i = 0; i < menuElements.length ; i++) {
      menuElements[i].addEventListener('click', change, false);
    }
  }

  var clear = function() {
    var menuElements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-tab]');
    for(var i = 0; i < menuElements.length ; i++) {
      menuElements[i].classList.remove('active');
      var id = menuElements[i].getAttribute('data-tab');
      document.getElementById(id).classList.remove('active');
    }
  }

  var change = function(e) {
    clear();
    e.target.classList.add('active');
    var id = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-tab');
    document.getElementById(id).classList.add('active');
  }

  bindAll();
}

var connectTabs = new Tabs();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this:

```
'use strict';

function Tabs() {
  var bindAll = function() {
    var menuElements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-tab]');
    for(var i = 0; i < menuElements.length ; i++) {
      menuElements[i].addEventListener('click', change, false);
    }
  }

  var clear = function() {
    var menuElements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-tab]');
    for(var i = 0; i < menuElements.length ; i++) {
      menuElements[i].classList.remove('active');
      var id = menuElements[i].getAttribute('data-tab');
      document.getElementById(id).classList.remove('active');
    }
  }

  function makeAllActive() {
    var tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.b-tab');
    Array.from(tabs).map(item => {
      item.classList.add('active');
    });
  }

  var change = function(e) {
    clear();
    e.target.classList.add('active');
    var id = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-tab');
    if(id === "green") {
      makeAllActive();
      return;
    }
    document.getElementById(id).classList.add('active');
  }

  bindAll();
}

var connectTabs = new Tabs();
```